# Unable to `apt-get` upgrade: How can I replace corrupted `systemd` `.conf` files?

Tags: apt, dpkg, systemd, vim

I am unable to `apt-get upgrade` because I received the following error:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up systemd (229-4ubuntu21.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 cannot compute MD5 hash for file '/etc/dbus-
1/system.d/org.freedesktop.resolve1.conf': failed to read 
(Input/output error)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have located `org.freedesktop.resolve1.conf`. Attempting to `cat` the contents gives me a `Input/Output error` but using `vim`, the file appears empty. How should I resolve this? Delete the file?

Comment: Have you run a filesystem and disk check recently?  That's just a text file.

Comment: Thanks, I have. And, I knew that the disk was failing but was postponing replacing it until now for financial reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An I/O error almost always indicates a failing hard drive. Back up you important data immediately, and use SMART to make sure of that. Then get a new drive and reinstall.

Comment: Ah, yes I am aware that my hard drive has been on the outward bound. Thanks for the tip. I will order a new storage device.